# In selenium IDE , how to store text message value of alert popup

Tags: selenium-ide

Which command is used in selenium ide for store/verify  text value of alert or confirmation popup

Answer (score 0):

**storeText(locator, variableName)** command is used in selenium IDE for store text value.

for example,

- in Alert message, text value have locator **X**
- you want to store that message in variable **Var**

So you can write command **storeText | X | Var**

Now, for compare this message with defined message then, First store message in a variable.

**store(expression, variableName)** command is used to store value in variable

in Your case, you can store message **Y** in variable **Var1**

So  you can write command **store |Y | Var1**

For compare messages you can user below command

**verifyEval | storedVars['Var']==storedVars['Var1'] | true**

Running this script as written will cause the test to Pass if two 
strings are matched and fail with [error] if two strings are not matched.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome @VaishaliBajpai

Comment: this command is not working when alert message display on popup with ok button

Comment: @VaishaliBajpai
when alert message display on popup with ok button Try this one

1) To store text of an alert message
**storeAlert | alertText**

2) Then store alert text value to variable so you can compare it with your expected message.
**store | ${alertText} | Var**
  - It will store alert Text value in variable "Var".

I hope it works for you

Comment: @Avinsh Patel... Thanks ... Its working ... but still i am not able to click yes button on confirmation/alert popup

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about default javascript alert or confirmation there are two commands for it:

**storeAlert**

```
Returns:
    The message of the most recent JavaScript alert

Retrieves the message of a JavaScript alert generated during the previous action, or fail if there were no alerts.

Getting an alert has the same effect as manually clicking OK. If an alert is generated but you do not consume it with getAlert, the next Selenium action will fail.

Under Selenium, JavaScript alerts will NOT pop up a visible alert dialog.

Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK.
```

**storeConfirmation**

```
Returns:
    the message of the most recent JavaScript confirmation dialog

Retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog generated during the previous action.

By default, the confirm function will return true, having the same effect as manually clicking OK. This can be changed by prior execution of the chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation command.

If an confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with getConfirmation, the next Selenium action will fail.

NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a visible dialog.

NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually click OK.
```

Check this out also: [Working example](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.nl/2013/10/selenium-ide-what-is-use-of.html)